# Get how many characters sscanf has read? (%n)

Tags: c, scanf

I have a string structured such as "[first something]=[second something"]

I think sscanf would be a way to seperate them!

However, scan never reports the offset properly with %n.

The line of code is something very much like:

```
char data[100];
char source[] = "username=katy"
int offset=-1;
sscanf([source],"%[^=],%s%n",data,&offset)
printf("sscanf is reporting %s with an offset of %i\n"

)
```

but the output always looks like:

```
sscanf is reporting username with an offset of -1
```

Could someone be so kind as to clear this up for me?

(Yes, I know this leaves us prone to a buffer overflow error - that is garuneteed against a little earlier in the code...)

Comment: It would be helpful to show us the exact code, rather than something "very much like" it. Your `sscanf` call is a syntax error (`[source]` isn't a valid expression), and your `printf` call is missing two arguments. You've determined that your actual `sscanf` call is incorrect, but we can't diagnose it without seeing it, and you presumably don't know what information you can safely omit.

Answer (score 3):

Your comma in the `scanf` format string makes no sense. Instead of `"%[^=],%s%n"`, try `"%[^=]=%s%n"`. You should also put field width limits on both of the strings or else you could overflow the destination buffers, and you've passed too few arguments to `sscanf` (only one of the strings, not the other one).

A corrected version of the code might look like:

```
char key[100], data[100];
char source[] = "username=katy"
int offset=-1;
sscanf(source,"%99[^=]=%99s%n",key,data,&offset)
printf("sscanf is reporting %s with an offset of %i\n", data, offset);
```

Comment: I regretfully admit I find the "manipulation" syntax a bit confusing... what exactly does key do, sir?

Comment: `%[` is a conversion specifier that outputs something. You were not giving it anywhere to write its output. Or, if you wanted its output to go to `data`, then the `%s` specifier had nowhere to write its output.